# Gnuplot - use different line colors for average bar

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a simple CSV file consisting of 3 columns: *date, value 1, value 2*. I'm using gnuplot to create a stacked bar chart and I'd like the last bar (average values) to be plotted with a different color. I'm using the following script:

```
set terminal png size 1000, 500
set output "bars.png"
set title "Trends"
set style data histograms
set style histogram rowstacked
set yrange [0:*]
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 0.9
set xlabel "Clicks"
set ylabel "Dates"
set xtics right rotate by 45
set datafile separator ","
plot newhistogram,  "data.csv" using 2:xtic(1) title "Direct" linecolor rgb "#0000ff",'' using 3 title "Indirect" linecolor rgb '#00ff00'
```

Sample input data file:

```
2023-01-11,234,8756
2023-01-13,54,876
2023-01-14,3333,3566
2023-01-15,543,654
2023-01-16,657,767
2023-01-17,876,88
2023-01-18,1606,55
2023-01-20,888,77
Average,1024,1855
```

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1PX5.png)

I tried to use a conditional value for linecolor but I'm getting an error I can't understand:

`gnuplot> plot newhistogram,  "/tmp/csv.csv" using 2:xtic(1) title "Direct" linecolor rgb "#0000ff", '' using 3 linecolor rgb (strcol(1) eq "Average" ? '#ff50ff' : '#43FF00') ^ line 0: stringcolumn() called from invalid context`

Comment: Your EDIT is an answer to your question. Please put this separately into an answer. You can answer your own question and accept it, indicating that the original problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to use a conditional for the *linecolor* directive, so I ended up with a conditional for *using*. The updated *plot* command which does the trick is as follows:

```
plot newhistogram, "data.csv" \
   using (strcol(1) ne 'Average' ? $2 : NaN):xtic(1) title "Direct" lc rgb "#0000ff", \
'' using (strcol(1) ne 'Average' ? $3 : NaN) title "Indirect" lc rgb '#00ff00', \
'' using (strcol(1) eq 'Average' ? $2 : NaN) notitle lc rgb '#0088ff', \
'' using (strcol(1) eq 'Average' ? $3 : NaN) notitle lc rgb '#00ff88'
```

The first 2 lines plot the rows not starting with 'Average' and the last 2 plot the last row which does. Each column's color is plotted with an arbitrary color.
The output now looks as intended.

[barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dneyK.png)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't know how to set conditional colors in the plotting style `with histogram`. Maybe there is a way which I am not aware of.
Since your data is relatively simple I would go via plotting style `with boxxyerror` (check `help boxxyerror`). There your have full flexibility, but have to think a bit more what you are plotting. Check the following example:

**Script:**

```
### bar chart with conditional colors
reset session

$Data <<EOD
2023-01-11,234,8756
2023-01-13,54,876
2023-01-14,3333,3566
2023-01-15,543,654
2023-01-16,657,767
2023-01-17,876,88
2023-01-18,1606,55
2023-01-20,888,77
Average,1024,1855
EOD

set title "Trends"
set style histogram rowstacked
set yrange [0:*]
set style fill solid
set xlabel "Clicks"
set ylabel "Dates"
set xtics right rotate by 45
set datafile separator ","

set offsets 0.5,0.5,0,0
myBoxwidth = 0.9
myColor(colD,colL) = (avg = strcol(colL) eq "Average" , \
                  colD==2 ? avg ? 0xaaaaff : 0x000ff : avg ? 0xaaffaa : 0x00ff00)

plot $Data u 0:($2/2):   (myBoxwidth/2.):($2/2):(myColor(2,1)):xtic(1) w boxxy ti "Direct"   lc rgb var, \
        '' u 0:($2+$3/2):(myBoxwidth/2.):($3/2):(myColor(3,1))         w boxxy ti "Indirect" lc rgb var
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, the graph is exactly as I wanted it but I'd rather not use *boxxyerror*. I'm very novice to gnuplot and I prefer something that I can understand easily, should I return to  it later.